# Is it possible to work with laravel without routes?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, routes

Asp.net MVC enables you to work with "automatic routes" through the following default configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

That way, when I type "site/controller/method" automatically the route is created according to naming conventions.

I'm starting now with Laravel, but from what I've seen, every route must be set manually. Is there any way to work with Laravel in the same way that works in Asp.net MVC on this issue of routes?

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn about resource controllers. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers):

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code. For example, you may wish to create a controller that handles all HTTP requests for "photos" stored by your application. Using the  make:controller Artisan command, we can quickly create such a controller:

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

And this route will create `index`, `create`, `store`, `edit`, `update` and `delete` routes for the resource:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Comment: Too quick on the edit for me :) T̶o̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶,̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶R̶o̶u̶t̶e̶:̶:̶r̶e̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶(̶'̶c̶a̶t̶s̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶C̶a̶t̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶'̶)̶;̶`

Comment: @btl just added. )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But in this case, this does not become automatic. You still need to set path and controller. This is not automatic, the framework is not reading the routes using naming conventions, it is reading a defined rule.

Comment: This is 2 lines of code. How much more automatic do you need?

Comment: Just curious to know if it's possible. Because the documentation seems to be the only way (defining routes), I wonder if it is possible or not to create a generic route for any controller.